# MS Access Issue assigning a values from a record set into text boxes

Tags: ms-access

This is pretty easy question, but I have been unable to find the solution using google.  More than likely I am using the wrong terminology.  Any help in addressing my issue or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Due an in house requirement at my company, I am creating an Access  database with an ODBC connection to SQL Server to maintain a user defined table.  It has been a while since I have programmed in VBA.

I am using an Access Form to pull up the data to be edited.  With a button press, a query runs and brings back one row based on the criteria.  I am using a record set to hold the information pulled back from the query.  My goal is to then put the data from the query into text boxes where they can be edited, then do an update statement with the changes made.  However, the code I wrote to put the record set data into the various text boxes is failing and I'm not able to figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
    'add rows to record set
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Parent_Name, Child_Name, Address, City, State, Zip, CustomerID, Facility, SystemID, " & _
            "from Table where CustomerID = '" & Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cbx_Cust_ID & "' and  Facility = '" & Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cbx_Facility & "' and SystemID = '" & _
            Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cmb_SystemID & "';")

rst.MoveLast

Me.txt_Edit_IDN_Name.Text = rst.Fields("Parent_Name").Value
Me.txt_Edit_Customer_ID.Text = rst.Fields("CustomerID").Value
Me.txt_Edit_Facility.Text = rst.Fields("Child_Name").Value
Me.txt_Edit_Facility_Num.Text = rst.Fields("Facility").Value
Me.txt_Edit_Address.Text = rst.Fields("Address").Value
Me.txt_Edit_City.Text = rst.Fields("City").Value
Me.cmb_Edit_State.Text = rst.Fields("State").Value
Me.txt_Edit_Zip.Text = rst.Fields("Zip").Value
Me.cmb_Edit_SystemID.Text = rst.Fields("SystemID").Value
```

I think the way I am attempting to reference the data in the record set is wrong, but I'm not able to figure out where I went wrong or use the proper terminology to find a solution via Google.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have multiple issues with that code.  Before discussing them I will offer you this advice.  Telling us your code fails is **nowhere near as useful** as telling us "`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` triggers error #3141, '*The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect*.'"

Discard the comma after `SystemID` in your `SELECT` statement field list.  The last field expression can't be followed by a comma or you will trigger error #3141.

Store your `SELECT` statement in a string variable, then `Debug.Print` it before you use it to open the recordset.

```
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "Select Parent_Name, Child_Name, Address, City, " & _
    "State, Zip, CustomerID, Facility, SystemID " & _
    "from [Table] where CustomerID = '" & _
    Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cbx_Cust_ID & "' and  Facility = '" & _
    Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cbx_Facility & "' and SystemID = '" & _
    Forms!Frm_Edit_Child!cmb_SystemID & "';"
Debug.Print strSelect
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
```

Then if you still encounter an error on `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`, you can go to the Immediate window (CTRL+g) to view the statement you're asking the db engine to use.  You may spot the problem as soon as you see the actual completed statement.  If not, you can copy the statement and paste it into SQL View of a new query ... figure out what changes are needed to avoid the error, then revise your VBA code so that it produces the same correct SQL statement.  If that still doesn't fix you up, paste the SQL into your question and tell us what error message you get from *that* SQL.

`Table` is a reserved word.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T).  If you must keep that as the table name, enclose it in square brackets to avoid confusing Access' db engine.

There could be a problem with this next line if your application includes a reference for Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects and it has a higher precedence than DAO.

```
Dim rst As Recordset
```

It's safer to explicitly declare the type of recordset you want.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
```

Drop `.Text` from lines like these as @user247245 suggested.  The `.Text` property is only available for the control which currently has focus.

```
Me.txt_Edit_IDN_Name.Text
```

You want `.Value` instead.  You can add it, but you don't need to because `.Value` is the default property.  So these 2 are functionally equivalent:

```
Me.txt_Edit_IDN_Name.Value
Me.txt_Edit_IDN_Name
```

Finally, I think this situation would be much simpler with a form bound to the `SELECT` statement.  You wouldn't have to fill your text box values because Access will do that for you automagically with bound controls.  You could revise the form's Record Source based on `cbx_Cust_ID`, `cbx_Facility`, and `cmb_SystemID` in the after update events of those controls or from the click event of a command button.  If the code you showed us is from a different form (not `Frm_Edit_Child`), you would have to use the command button approach.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That fixed my problem.  Now I am off to look into using a form bound with a select statement.  If that's a better option,  I will happily use that.  I am sorry I forgot to put the specific problem.  I was trying to make sure I covered everything and totally blanked on that.  Oh, and the table isn't named table, but it is named something specific based on our industry and so I changed it to the generic table for the sake of posting the code.  Next time I will use a non-reserved word generic name.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but:

- Is .Text the way to go? Try omitting.
- Why not link the source table (to a linked MS-Acess table) and apply a filter on the form? No need for code at all. The query is easy for JET to parse so little bandwidth. Or an integrity/security concern?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I'm going to look into this and using a form bound to the select statement and once I figure out how to do it, use that instead.  I was able to fix the problem based on the advice though!

Comment: @Azzna, Thinking about it, you may want to stay away from VBA. MS-Office security policies regarding VBA can be a pain with many clients to configure.